# How to make an arraylist that stores infomration from 3 different classes

Tags: java

I have an assignment where I need to make a program that stores student information. I need to apply concepts of inheritance and interfaces.
I need to create an Arraylist that stores info from 3 different classes. Attached is the program description and features.  I want a general idea of what I need to do to implement this program.[cord](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVT27.png)

Comment: What have you done so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create objects list

```
List<Object> objects = new ArrayList<>();
```

Add different objects to the objects list:

```
objects.add(1232);

objects.add("Some string");

objects.add(122.212f);
```

Check element type with for loop:

```
for (Object obj : objects) {

   if (obj.getClass() == String.class) {

       System.out.println(" string :- " + obj);

   }

   if (obj.getClass() == Integer.class) {

       System.out.println(" int :- " + obj);

   } 

   if (obj.getClass() == Float.class) {    

       System.out.println(" float :- " + obj);

   } 
 }
```

Comment: Or use instanceof operator to check object class -  if(obj instanceof String)

Answer (score 1):

Create a super class or an interface with a meaningful name that is related to those all 3 classes and then extend that super class or implement that interface to each of these classes .

When you create a list put the super class type or the interface type in the list.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a common superclass for all informatio so you can use it as a type:

```
List<YourSuperclass>
```

But conisdering your task, you should follow composition over inheritance:

```
public class Student {
  private List<Course> courses;
  private String name;

  ...
}
```

So you could do:

```
List<Student> students
```

Then you could find the courses of a student:

```
students.get(0).getCourses()
```